# Function evaluation timed out

Tags: wcf

I have WCF service.. couple times it was working ok.. but after certain point in time the function returns "Function evaluation timedout".. what the heck is this? also, when I checked the state of the proxy it was opened.. can anyone please help?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess it is one of two things. Either it is a custom error in your application or it is stuck on a debug point. Refer: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/728b9404-60b1-4951-99f8-70a5f75cba61/

Please supply more information about what the service is doing.

Comment: the client proxy call the service in asych fashion and performing update to the database (nothing fancy). And the same proxy is used by the client to call another method in the service. This is what I'm suspecting is the proxy being locked up by the first call but I can't figure out myself how to get around this..

Comment: Could you post some example code from the client to show how it makes these two calls

Comment: Sorry privacy reason I cannot post the code.. But I figured out the problem was.. To solve the issue I use multithreading on the service side. The first called method in the service can immediately finish and return the call to the client before client making the second call to the service.. Now the problem is how do i capture the error on the client side if the first called method produces an error?